# Working with "Databricks Community Edition" using visual studio code in 2023

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, integration, databricks-community-edition

Is there a way, in 2023, to work with DATABRICKS COMMUNITY EDITION using VSCode?

I understand that there is NO TOKEN generation available for community edition.

But is there a workaround (back door kind of thing) or something?

If you have any tips for using VSCode with DATABRICS COMMUNITY EDITION, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against attempting to use unofficial workarounds or "backdoor" methods to gain functionality that is not openly supported by Databricks Community Edition, as this could potentially breach the terms of service of the platform and result in the suspension or termination of your account, not to mention the potential security risks involved.

It is true the "[Manage personal access tokens](https://docs.databricks.com/en/administration-guide/access-control/tokens.html#manage-personal-access-tokens)" mentions:

> Managing personal access tokens in your workspace requires the [Premium plan or above](https://databricks.com/product/pricing/platform-addons).

But the [Databricks extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=databricks.databricks) also mentions:

> Permission to access the workspace using a personal access token (PAT) **or [Azure AD CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest)**.

So check if using that extension after a simple `az login` is enough.